# Anaconda custom endpoint

Tags: amazon-ec2, anaconda

I'm trying to set up an anaconda cluster within a private ec2 cloud so the default region endpoints are not available.  While setting up the providers.yaml file I noticed it errors explicitly on not finding my regions.

Is there a way for me to further debug/trace what's going on behind the cloud_provider:ec2 setting within the providers.yaml file or otherwise hardcode the backend to point at my custom endpoint instead of the public AWS cloud?

A similar custom ec2 enabled cloud as I'm referring to can be found here:
https://qstack.advania.com/login

Any help well appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda Cluster does not support launching instances in private EC2 clouds or regions, you can only launch instances on the public AWS cloud via the `ec2` provider.

For a more manual approach, you can launch the instances via other means, then "provision" the running instances following the bare-metal cluster installation process in the [Anaconda Cluster documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda-cluster/). Then, you'll be able to install conda packages and analytics engines with Anaconda Cluster as usual.